# UnCaught TypeError : Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined at - While trying to display HTTP Response

Tags: java, android, http-get

Android 2.3.3

I am trying to use a HTTP Get request and get a (AD) Script/HTML from the server. After getting the response I am trying to attach the response to a WebView. I get the response correctly from the server everytime. I get either HTML or a Script. But sometimes the ad gets displayed and sometimes not. Please refer to the below details

Logcat...

```
        05-31 15:36:33.339: E/Web Console(10861): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined at 
http://lp.xxx.xx/rich/T/test_suite/smartphone/320x50_ex_launch.php?mm_view=js&mm_urid=ZyAOlvcAeXFxzt4seOQ0WWwL&mm_ipaddress=49.205.242.120
    &mm_handset=3768&mm_carrier=0&mm_apid=xxxxx&mm_acid=465355&mm_osid=58
    &mm_uip=49.205.242.120&mm_ua=Apache-HttpClient%2FUNAVAILABLE+%28java+1.4%29
    &mm_mtpid=0&mm_hswd=320&mm_hsht=53
    &mm_auid=mmid_11a58a0069120505278791da8d22d5ad28_013ec7373911
    &mm_country=100&mm_orut=1369994770&mm_mmid=3768:495
```

Java Code - AsyncTask - Works Fine

```
public static class GetMMediaAdsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    String url = "http://ads.mp.xxx.xx/getAd";
    String apid = "xxx";
    String auid = "";

    String returned = "";

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public GetMMediaAdsTask(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);      
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();


        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("***** Inside AsyncTask *****");

        auid = Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        int hsht = 0;
        int hswd = 0;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        System.out.println("Height ="+height+" Width = "+width);

        if(width <= 320)
        {
            hswd = 320;
            hsht = 53;
        }
        else if(width > 320 && width < 468)
        {
            hswd = 320;
            hsht = 53;
        }
        else if(width >= 468 && width < 728)
        {
            hswd = 468;
            hsht = 60;
        }
        else if(width >= 728)
        {
            hswd = 728;
            hsht = 90;
        }

        String query = String.format("apid=%s&auid=%s&hsht=%d&hswd=%d", apid, auid, hsht, hswd);
        System.out.println("query = "+query);

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpMethod = new HttpGet();
            httpMethod.setURI(new URI(url + "?" + query));
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(httpMethod);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("Response Code = "+ responseCode);

            switch (responseCode) {
            case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    returned = "";
                    returned = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    System.out.println("response = "+returned);

                }
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("***** Inside PostExecute *****");
        responseBody = returned;
        System.out.println("responseBody = "+responseBody);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mArticlePagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mPosition);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                setShareIntent(position);
                if (mOnPageSelectedListener != null)
                    mOnPageSelectedListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


        progressDialog.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Code in MainActivity

```
private static GetMMediaAdsTask mGetMMediaAds;

static String responseBody = "";

StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
....
....
html.append("<p>");
String url = "http://xxxx.com/getAd";

mGetMMediaAds = new GetMMediaAdsTask(context);
mGetMMediaAds.execute(url); // Calling the execute method of asynctask

...
...
...
html.append(responseBody);
html.append("</p>");
```

Please let me know, if you need anything...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Millennial Media placement is calling for expandable banners. When using a server to server implementation, Millennial Media does not support expandable banners.  The error is just saying it is looking for javascript in an it will not find.  When this happens, it is best to change your placement to not allow expandable banners.

Thank you,

Aaron